# Partial view in MVC3 Razor view Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an view in MVC3 Razor view engine like following image. Now i want to Confirm Connection Action Output show under this link text not New page. How can i done this work?

Please explain with example code.

[image]

My View Like this :

```
@model ESimSol.BusinessObjects.COA_ChartsOfAccount
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dynamic Account Head Configure";
}

<h2>Dynamic Account Head Configure</h2>

<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td> Select an Server Connection </td>
        <td style="width:5px">:</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DBConnections, Model.DBConnections.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ConnectionName, Value =  x.DBConnectionID.ToString()}))</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td style="width:5px"></td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Confirm Connection", "ConformConnection")</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

AND My Controller action Like following :

```
public ActionResult ConfirmConnection()
        {           
            return PartialView();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First move your markup to a partial view. After that define an action method that renders your partial view.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ConfirmConnection(COA_ChartsOfAccount model)
{           
    return PartialView("MyPartialView", model);
}
```

ChildActionOnly attribute makes sure this action method cannot be called by a HTTP request.

Then you can display it whenever you want using Html.Action method.

```
@Html.Action("ConfirmConnection", "MyController", new { model = Model })
```

Ignore passing the model as a parameter if it doesn't change by the page you display it. You can retrieve it in your action method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of using jquery and ajax for this kind of thing ...
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you are following the typical MVC model then you can add an action link to the page using something like ...

```
@Html.ActionLink("controller", "action", args);
```

but I would go for the ajax driven approach ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxBaseUrl = '@Url.Action("yourController", "ConformConnection", new { args })';
        $(link).click(function () {
            var currentElement = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxBaseUrl,
                data: { any other queryString stuff u want to pass },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                        // action to take when the ajax call comes back
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```